# Where can I get each of the following currencies?

Tags: the-secret-world

In The Secret World, there are six currencies as far as I can tell.

These are:

- Black Mark of Venice
- White Mark of Venice
- Sequin of Solomon Island
- Sequin of the Valley of the Sun Gods
- Sequin of Transylvania
- Black Button

The sequins are given as a quest reward in each of the relevant areas, so completing quests on Solomon Island will reward you with Sequins of Solomon Island.

Where do I get the Black/White Mark of Venice and Black Buttons from?

Comment: Black and white come from pvp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Black Mark of Venice => PVP

White Mark of Venice => PVP

Sequin of Solomon Island => Solomon Island Zones (kingsmouth, Savage Coast, Blue Mountains)

Sequin of the Valley of the Sun Gods => Egypt zones

Sequin of Transylvania => Transylvania zones

Black Button => Nightmare Dungeons

Comment: Might aswell add that you only get (either white or black) from the Stonehenge and the other. And you get both from doing the quests from project.

Comment: I have never PVP'd and I have 4707 white mark of venice so they aren't just from PVP

Comment: You get white marks if your faction controls pvp objectives, even if you don't pvp yourself